# How to express x1, y1, x2, y2 from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem in which I need to find the perimeter of a quadrilateral, knowing only the coordinates of the points. As I type, I have `"# LB3: 5 # RB5: 5 # LT1: 1 # RT2: 6"`. I use regex and drop numbers.

To calculate the perimeter of a quadrilateral, first I need to find `dist`. As from the list `a`, I express `x1, y1, x2, y2`

```
dist = sqrt ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
```

My code:

```
def perimetr(data):
    a = []
    result = re.findall(r'\d',data)
    for i in result:
        a.append(i)
    #dist = sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
    return a
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: Delete the handwritten image and just show how the `data` argument looks like in the code

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You can index the list: `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc. Note that `findall` already returns a list; there's no need to copy its elements into a new list `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Retrieve data

- You need to extract only the real data, the ones not stuck to a word, I'd suggest word boundary `\b` for that, so the regex `\b\d+\b`
- `re.findall` already returns a list
- you have a list of `str`, you need integers : `map(int, re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', data))`

---

#### Coordinate definition

1. list indexing

   ```
   dist = sqrt((a[2] - a[0]) ** 2 + (a[3] - a[1]) ** 2)
   ```
2. unpacking

   ```
   x1, y1, x2, y2 = a
   ```

---

#### Math about perimeter

The perimeter is the length of the sides, the formula is so

```
2 * (x2 - x1) + 2 * (y2 - y1)
```

Your formula `sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)` is about Pythagore and the hypothenus length, so in your case the diagonal length

---

### Solution

```
def perimetr(data):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', data))
    return sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
```